# ReorderableList in Unity with Enums

Tags: unity, c#, game-design, gui

I'm trying to setup a simple ReorderableList in Unity 2017.3 for a list of enums. Adding items workes fine but selecting, dragging and deleting items from the list does not (see gif).

[image]

Here is my code:

```
[Serializable]
public enum RoofType { HIP, GABLE, FLAT, NONE }


UnityEditorInternal.ReorderableList roofTypeList = new UnityEditorInternal.ReorderableList(roofTypes, typeof(RoofType), true, true, true, true);
roofTypeList.drawHeaderCallback = (Rect rect) =>
{
   EditorGUI.LabelField(rect, "Roof types");
};
roofTypeList.drawElementCallback = (Rect rect, int index, bool isActive, bool isFocused) =>
{
   roofTypes[index] = (RoofType)EditorGUI.EnumPopup(rect, roofTypes[index]);
};
roofTypeList.DoLayoutList();
```

Any ideas why this does not work? My guess it is because I use enums and not classes but it is not documented anywhere.

Comment: Is all of the code in your snippet within `OnInspectorGUI()`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be re-creating the ReorderableList on each execution of OnInspectorGUI(). Unlike other types of inspector UI elements, this one should be instantiated elsewhere, and a reference to that instance should be used in OnInspectorGUI() instead. For example (based on [this article](http://va.lent.in/unity-make-your-lists-functional-with-reorderablelist/)):

```cs
public class MyListEditor : Editor
{
    private ReorderableList list;
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        list = new UnityEditorInternal.ReorderableList(roofTypes, typeof(RoofType), true, true, true, true);
    }
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        list.DoLayoutList();
    }
}
```

I'll also note that the above linked article recommends using the SerializedObject version of the ReorderableList() constructor. Give that a try if you're still having trouble.